# I need help to draw graph like attached screenshots for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, graph, linechart

I've tried lots of graphs but didn't got the success. All the graph will update dynamically based on the heart rate and Average speed in realtime update using monitor and GPS respectively.

1. This graph will show the data that user had spent how much time in a particular zones.
2. This design will show the completion of challenge based on the percentage, other user's profile will move with the percentage of completion.
3. This design will show heart rate during the exercise for range from zone 1to 5, Same data will available which i want to draw on image no 1(Above first image). White portion in orange colour is a indicator which will follow the different colour path as per heart rate count shown in same design.

[image: This graph will show the data that user had spent how much time in a particular zones.]

[image: This design will show the completion of challenge based on the percentage, other user's profile will move with the percentage of completion.]

[image: This design will show heart rate during the exercise for range from zone 1to 5, Same data will available which i want to draw on image no 1(Above first image). White portion in orange colour is a indicator which will follow the different colour path as per heart rate count shown in same design.]

Comment: you should try some code than you want to share code for solution that is the right way to question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many options and create online using highcharts. And implement in a Native application. Download HTML file and set something like that as you want in your comment section.

[Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)

```
        func drawChart(barsData:NSMutableArray){

        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: barsData, options: (JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)))
        let theJSONText = NSString(data: jsonData,
                                   encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
        let htmlFile: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourHTML", ofType: "html")
        var htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let oldWdith = "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 380px; height: 180px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>"
        let ReplaceWdith = "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: \(width)px; height: 180px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>"
        htmlString = htmlString?.replacingOccurrences(of: oldWdith, with: ReplaceWdith)
        yourWbview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: htmlString! as String)
        yourWbview.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried but it not providing scrolling in graph for previous passed data.

Comment: Yes, it provides. you need to increase the width of a graph in HTML file.

Comment: In body tag you need to pass 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 1000; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

Comment: Yes but there may be statics limit of graph.But I need to update graph dynamically based on the heart rate. it causes problem to scroll more for updated data. is there any other way to do this thing?

Comment: Yes, you can do it dynamically, you just have to get the HTML string and replace that string.  suppose Put a static word in HTML file. and get HTML string from the HTML file programmatically and replace that string to your dynamic width and load in webview.

Comment: Have you got it @jignesh ?

Comment: Hi kalpesh
Thanks for the help. We achieved which we need for graph.But still getting problem with the second graph. I didn't get the how we'll design it in HTML or JS. We need to move second user image based on percentage of task completion(Challenge task). If you can help me out then it will be a lot for me.